# Sinatra App Not Updating Database

Tags: sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

I'm trying to create a simple webapp to record notes for school, but the database isn't updating like I think it should be.  Here's the code.

The sinatra app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/school.db")

class Note
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :class, Text, :required => true
  property :title, Text, :required => true
  property :content, Text, :required => true
  property :created_at, DateTime
  property :updated_at, DateTime
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

get '/school' do
  #
  # @notes is nil
  #

  @notes = Note.all
  @title = 'Notes'
  erb :school
end

get '/' do
  @title = 'Home'
  erb :index
end

get '/addnote' do
  erb :addnote
end

post '/addnote' do
  n = Note.new
  n.class = params[:class]
  n.content = params[:content]
  n.created_at = Time.now
  n.updated_at = Time.now
  n.save

  redirect '/school'
end
```

And here's the form

```
<section id="add">
  <form action="/addnote" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="class" placeholder="Class" />
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Take Note"/>
  </form>
</section>
```

Thanks

Comment: You are missing from your question the details about what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to set the `title` attribute in your `post /addnote` route.

It is declared as `required` in your model and does not get set.

Try to add this to your that route to see if it gets saved:

```
if n.save
  redirect '/school'
else
  #show an error or something
end
```